# Inline css in html

Tags: html, css

Is there any easy and fast way to inline css in html? This is my sample html which I am using in my code

```css
.table > thead > tr > th {
    border: solid #000 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    border: solid #000 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
    background-color: #2882d7 ;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    background-color: #f5f5f5 ;
    color: #000;
    font-family: verdana;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>James</td>
                    <td>james1985@html.in</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html
try the above link, it helped me

Comment: Why would you want to inline the CSS?

Comment: Do you mean you have a ton of external stylesheet references and you want a program to automatically convert them into `<style>` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `<style>` block in the header for example, and put the style rules in there:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can put the styling in the `style` attribute for each of the elements:
    ...

The former will basically put the CSS-file and the HTML-document in one single file. So you can still use classes and such.

The latter is setting the element style, so it's a less elegant way to make e.g. two elements the same.

Answer (score -1):

There's more than a few ways to do it but here are the ones I know and use.

- [Foundation's Inliner](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html) - Manual
- [Using a Grunt plugin](https://github.com/jgallen23/grunt-inline-css) - Automatic

Answer (score -1):

Four ways to do it

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />`
2. ```
   <style media="screen" type="text/css">
     Add style rules here
   </style>
   ```
3. `<h2 style="color:red;background:black;">This is a red heading with a black background</h2>`
4. `@import "newstyles.css";`